# database design in django models for multiple columns for multiple rows.

Tags: python, django, django-models

[image: Table for database]

I am creating db design in my django product for the above data structure. I am a little confused as to how to represent it most optimally, should I be creating a table for each row  with table name as Organic manure and column names as the year name or is their a better way to represent the whole info in one table ?

Comment: would this be a one to one relationship ?

Comment: What do the values in the table represent?

Comment: @joeB1 - kgs/plant per each ascending year

Comment: This could be one table (as it is now).

Comment: You could have a product name, year and kgs value attribute (i.e column)

Comment: @joeB1 - and how would you do that ? a sample code snippet would help .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68569/discussion-between-scooby-and-joeb1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one-to-many relationship between the Product (manure, nitrogen, etc) and the Amount (year, value).

```
UNITS = (
    ('kg', 'kg'),
    ('g', 'g')
)
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unit = models.CharField(choices=UNITS)

class Amount(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```